# Evaluation recursive limit

Tags: limits, recurrence-relations

How to evaluate this limit:

$\lim_{x\to0^+}\dfrac { -1+\sqrt { \tan(x)-\sin(x)+\sqrt { \tan(x)-\sin(x)+\sqrt { \tan(x)-\sin(x) } +...\infty  }  }  }{ -1+\sqrt { { x }^{ 3 }+\sqrt { { x }^{ 3 }+\sqrt { x^{ 3 } } +...\infty  }  }  } $

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Let $\sqrt { \tan(x)-\sin(x)+\sqrt { \tan(x)-\sin(x)+\sqrt { \tan(x)-\sin(x) } +...\infty  }  }=y$

$\implies\tan(x)-\sin(x)+y=y^2$

$\implies y=?$

Similarly, for  $\sqrt { { x }^{ 3 }+\sqrt { { x }^{ 3 }+\sqrt { x^{ 3 } } +...\infty  }  } $

Comment: So its evaluating to 1/2 right? Thanks a ton :-)