# Why is this limit evaluated like so?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry

## Question:

If
$$\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{-1 + \sqrt{(\tan x - \sin x) + \sqrt{(\tan x - \sin x) + \sqrt{(\tan x - \sin x) + \cdots \infty}}}}{-1 + \sqrt{x^3 + \sqrt{x^3 + \sqrt{x^3 + \cdots \infty}}}}} = \frac{1}{k}$$

Then find the value of $k$.

---

The way I approached the problem was by substituting $x = 0$ in the limit:

$$\frac{-1 + \sqrt{(\tan 0 - \sin 0) + \sqrt{(\tan 0 - \sin 0) + \sqrt{(\tan 0 - \sin 0) + \cdots \infty}}}}{-1 + \sqrt{0^3 + \sqrt{0^3 + \sqrt{0^3 + \cdots \infty}}}} = \frac{1}{k}$$

$$\implies \frac{-1 + \sqrt{0 + \sqrt{0 + \sqrt{0 + \cdots \infty}}}}{-1 + \sqrt{0 + \sqrt{0 + \sqrt{0 + \cdots \infty}}}} = \frac{1}{k}$$

$$\implies \frac{-1}{-1} = \frac{1}{k}$$

$$\implies \frac{1}{1} = \frac{1}{k}$$

$$\implies k = 1$$

---

But according to the given solution, the answer is 2.

[image]

---

I did find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334811/evaluation-recursive-limit) question, but I do not understand why I cannot just put $x = 0$ in the limit.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Limit is not evaluated by plugging in general, but it can be done so if the function involved is continuous (this also forms a common definition of continuous function).

Comment: I was taught to first try substituting the value directly, and only proceed to other methods (L'Hospital, factorizing, etc.) if it resulted in an indeterminate form. But that might have been because we were working with simple limits. @ParamanandSingh

Comment: You were taught right. An elementary function is continuous on its domain. An elementary function is made using finite number of $+, -, \times, /$ and composition of algebraic, circular (direct/inverse), exponential and logarithmic functions. The function involved here is defined via a limiting procedure and hence is not exactly an elementary function.

Comment: OK. I understand now. Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. when we look at these continued roots....lets look at the one in the numerator, the logic will hold for the one in the denominator.

First the roots will not be defined as real functions if $x<0$

$\lim_\limits{x\to 0} \tan x - \sin x = 0$

$\tan x - \sin x > 0$ for all  $0<x<\frac {\pi}2$

When x is small and positive then $\tan x - \sin x$ will also be small and positive.

$\tan x - \sin x<\sqrt{\tan x - \sin x}$

We are looking at an infinite sequence.

$s_{n+1} = \tan x - \sin x + \sqrt {s_{n}}$

Where we are taking small positive numbers and adding something on, and since this sequence is infinite, it will eventually be something of non trivial magnitude no matter how small $\tan x - \sin x$ may have been at the start.

Eventually, it approaches 1,  but it can't get more than trivally larger than one.

Because if $s_n > 1, 1<\sqrt {s_n} < s_n$

This is why you can't treat it like you do continuous functions and just plug zero.

Comment: The way I thought about it is that if the function is continuous, then the $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)$ is equal to $f(0)$. Is the function not continuous at $x = 0$

Comment: If it were a finite number of roots $f(x) = \sqrt{\tan x - \sin x + \sqrt{\tan x - \sin x + \cdots}}$ would be continuous, But if it is infinite, it becomes a step function.

Comment: OK. I understand. Thank you for the help.